# Begginer- Doesn't let me input 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Doesn't let me to input values to x.
It runs and it says that is completed with exit code 0. Why?

```
def donuts():
    x = int(input("How many donutes?"))
    if x < 10:
        print("Numbers of donuts: "+ x)
    else:
        print("Number of donute: many")

def litere():
    x = input("Type a word! : ")
    if len(x) <= 2:
        print("NULL")
    else:
        k = len(x) -1
        print(x[0:3] + x[k-2])
if '  name  ' == '  main  ':
    donuts()
```

Comment: Remove the `' '` from around the `__name__`. It should be `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Do not post images of code, but the code itself, so helpers can copy and paste it. You have mixed indentation in your code: in the functions, you use two spaces, yet in the if-block at the bottom, you use 4 spaces.

Comment: It's not the solution but `print("Number of donuts: "+x)` should be `print("Number of donuts: "+str(x))` since `x` is an integer. You cannot print integers with strings without changing one of them.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Thank you @Dan !

Comment: Don't worry guys I edited the post so y'all can see the code

Answer (score 0):

`__name__` is a variable. It should have quotes around it. When you surround it with quotes python treats it like a regular string. Replace the bottom with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    donuts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes around `'__name__'` so it becomes `__name__`:

Answer (score 0):

```
def donuts():
    x = int(input("How many donutes?"))
    if x < 10:
        print("Numbers of donuts: "+ x)
    else:
        print("Number of donute: many")

def litere():
    x = input("Type a word! : ")
    if len(x) <= 2:
        print("NULL")
    else:
        k = len(x) -1
        print(x[0:3] + x[k-2])
if __name__  == "__main__":
    donuts()
```

Here is the change I made to your code:

```
if __name__  == "__main__":
    donuts()
```